sizzle magento error when selecting an image
I have a problem when i'm selecting an image in  the backend of magento to choose an image to a brand.
this is the error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /s/media/wysiwyg/magebig/brand/8.png
Sizzle.error=function(msg){throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+msg);}
I don't know how to fix that

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

when selecting an image on backend magento 2, there is always loading without doing anything and in console ihave thos error:
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /s/media/wysiwyg/magebig/brand/08.jpg
at Sizzle.error (jquery.min.js:118:402)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.min.js:152:44)
at Sizzle.select (jquery.min.js:189:168)
at Function.Sizzle (jquery.min.js:66:8)
